# How to add google keyboard (Gboard) into my own android studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gboard

I am working on a project on android. I want to attach Gboard into my application because I want to use its functions. I want to use Gboard pad for writing input. I don't want from the user to download Gboard separately. I want to make it a part of application. If possible kindly let me know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id say it is not possible, cannot find anything for Gboard, even [virtual keyboard api](https://developers.google.com/virtual-keyboard) is deprecated since 2011.

You might want to take a look at [creating your own input methods](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html).